# mongoose typescript compilation error with ts-node

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, ts-node

I'm getting the error: "Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | undefined'"
I'm using mongoose with ts-node

league.model.ts

```
import { model, Schema, Model, Document } from 'mongoose';

interface ILeague extends Document {
    name: string;
}

const LeagueSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true }
});

export const League = model('League', LeagueSchema);
....

 await League.findOneAndUpdate(query, league, options)
```

Comment: You might need to share more information to correctly answer it. I have removed the answer as it doesn't add any value to the post

Comment: What line does the error point to? What are `query`, `league` and `options`?